# How to pass data when changing views using ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that has a dynamic view, which I am implementing using an `ng-template`.
The following is that component, lets say `parent.component.ts`.

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: '<div><ng-template child-area></ng-template></div>',
    ...
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(ChildAreaDirective) childArea: ChildAreaDirective;

    loadComponent (details) {
        let _vcf = this.childArea.viewContainerRef;
        let _cf= resolveComponentFactory(childrenList[details.name]);

        // How do I pass the options object from here into the child component??
        this.childOptions = details.options;

        let componentRef = _vcf.createComponent(_cf);
    }
}
```

The `child.component.ts` is written like this:

```
@Component ({
    template: '<div>{{ title }}</div>'
})
```

I want to call the `loadComponent` method like this:

```
parent.loadComponent({ name: 'choose-doc', options: {title: "Main File"} });
```

How can I pass the `options` object into the child component, so that the title gets the value 'Main File'?

Answer (score 0):

componentRef has the attribute `instance` which is the actual instance of the created component. From this instance, you can access to all public attributes and functions of the component.

You can map your options inside a function on the component or just set them from `loadComponent`.

Check the class doc: https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#instance